# ActionBar: HomeAsUp with custom view

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have set a custom view for my ActionBar and I would like to enable homeAsUp. Everything works and the Up indicator is clickable. Now I want to make also the custom view clickable and touchable (like the normal app icon is). So I want to apply the state pressed (hover) effect also to the custom view. Ideally the Up indicator and custom view appear as one area. So when I click / touch the up indicator the custom view should be change his selector as well and vice versa. Is there an easy way to do that?

Btw: I can not make the app indicator part of the ActionBar custom view, because I use ActionBarDrawerToggle...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using "Toolbar" supported in appcompat support library.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create layout for custom action bar in order define functionality according to your requirement. Here is the xml file...

layout for custom action bar :

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_back_iv"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/small_margin_ar"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/very_small_margin_ar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/up_navigation"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_titleText_tv"
        style="@style/wrapscreen"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/custom_actionbar_back_iv"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/above_medium_text_size" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_goToArchiveActivity_ib"
        style="@style/wrapscreen"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/medium_margin"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here goes the implementation..

Define setupactionBar() method in onCreate() method

```
    private void setUpActionBar() {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View customActionBarView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

            // this view is used to show tile
            TextView ActivityTitleTV = (TextView) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_titleText_tv);
            ActivityTitleTV.setText(R.string.title_text_archive);

            //this view can be used for back navigation
            ImageView backToRecorderIV = (ImageView) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_back_iv);
            backToRecorderIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            backToRecorderIV.setOnClickListener(this);

            //Another view which has up navigation
            ImageButton goToArchiveActivityIB = (ImageButton) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_goToArchiveActivity_ib);
            goToArchiveActivityIB.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        }

        //listener for back navigation
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.custom_actionbar_back_iv:
                    Intent recorder = new Intent(ArchiveActivity.this, RecorderActivity.class);
                    startActivity(recorder);
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps...